# How to put a wrapped row in reverse order

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Im using `flexbox` to ordening some elements and i need reverse the elements order with CSS and it gets weird:

```
|4|3|2|1|
|8|7|6|5|
```

and I need it to be this way:

```
|8|7|6|5|
|4|3|2|1|
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 208px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row-reverse
}

li {
  min-width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You need 8 items one way and another 8 items another way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just make `flex-wrap:wrap-reverse`

```css
ul{
  list-style: none;
  width: 208px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  flex-direction: row-reverse
}

li {
  min-width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: so fast, thanks!